# Access Database - Create a table using data from two different sources

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am a new grad and my programming/database skills are very rudimentary. I was tasked with creating a database and ran into this one issue that I can't solve. I have to create a report that shows some testing results. There are two types of tests - custom tests and core test. All custom tests have a core attached to them. So I have two test IDs - Core ID and Custom ID. The Custom ID always has a Core ID that it can be tracked back to.

So I can't find a way to consolidate both custom and core results in one place and use that as a record source for my report. I tried making a temp table to get custom and core but then I can't consolidate that data that overlaps when I have a custom result that has a core id attached to it as well. Should I look into using VBA? I've tried using update, union, append query etc. but I can't reach a solution.

How can I create a table that extracts data from two different sources? and removes the duplicates. I've used union (tried UNION and UNION ALL as well) query but it omits data that has a core and custom. Some guidance will be greatly appreciated 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECEMA.png)

So I've attached a picture and this is where i get into troubles. The Custom is related to core and the data i need to fetch is in the core table. I have a table that links the custom to a specific core but then how do I tell Access to go to the core to fetch more details from the core table. Like I am having issues putting that logic in.

Comment: You will get more reply If you post sample of your tables and how you want the resulting data to look like. You will also get more replies by including QSL tag to your post.

Comment: Possibly just build report and use its Sorting & Grouping features or maybe a report/subreport.